# how to map urls.py for autocomplete

Tags: django-haystack

I'm new to Haystack as well as Django and Python.

I've followed the [Haystack Autocomplete tutorial](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html). I have added the following line to my urls.py: `url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),`

I also have elastic search running, and I can see that it builds the index properly.  However, how do I actually get the results in the app?  I tried hitting

`http://127.0.0.1:9000/search` and

`http://127.0.0.1:9000/search/autocomplete`

in my browser as a test, but I just get "Cannot get search" messages back. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Django port is 8000. Try that :)